# Keeping a Vega-Lite Schema Local

Tags: vega-lite, mkdocs

I was wondering if there was a way to keep a Vega-Lite schema local to a Gitlab project. Right now I've got my graph imbedded in code blocks inside of a .md file. And it works just fine.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with ranged data (aka Gantt Chart).",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"task": "A", "start": 1, "end": 3},
      {"task": "B", "start": 3, "end": 8},
      {"task": "C", "start": 8, "end": 10}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "task", "type": "ordinal"},
    "x": {"field": "start", "type": "quantitative"},
    "x2": {"field": "end"}
  }
}
```

I was wondering if I was able to reference the schema in my project something like this...

"$schema": "./schema/vega-lite/v5.json"